# Dynamically populate 3 dropdowns based on the selection in first dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have 4 dropdowns. Magazines, DD1, DD2, DD3. The dropdowns DD1, DD2, DD3 needs to be auto populated dynamically with the selection of a value in Magazine dropdown. The dropdowns DD1, DD2, DD3 are not dependent on each other. They purely depend on value in Magazines dropdown.

On the selection of dropdown 1 value, php ajax has to make call on mysql.  I need to implement 3 different mysql queries in the background for 3 dropdowns.I surfed in net and all dropdowns are related to the previous dropdowns. For [Example.](http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/)
Can anybody guide me with proper link or proper idea to do this.

[image]

Comment: @MatthewCliatt - I am telling that how to proceed and you are asking for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround using javascript onchange:

form:

```
<select name="dd1" id="dd1" class="form-control" onChange="getDD2(this.value);">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-select-</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
function getDD2(id){
            if(id==""){
                alert("Please select any dd1!");            
            }else{
            var url = 'getdd2.php?id='+id;
                $('#dd2container').load(url);
            }
        }
```

and in getdd2.php

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$dd= "SELECT * FROM prefix_dd2 WHERE id='$id'";
$founddd1 = $dbh->query($dd);
$res = $founddd1->fetchAll();
if(count($res)<=0){
    echo '<select name="dd2" class="form-control" id="dd2">';
            echo '<option value="select">No dd</option>';           
    echo "</select>";   
}else{
    echo '<select name="dd2" class="form-control" id="dd2" onchange="getDD3($id)">';
    echo '<option value="select" selected="selected">-select-</option>';
        foreach($res as $dd2):
            echo '<option value="'.$dd2['id'].'">'.$dd2['dd2_name'].'</option>';
        endforeach;
    echo "</select>";
}
```

DD2 select in your form would be:

```
<div id="dd2container">
  <select name="dd2" class="form-control">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now you can make getDD3() function like I did getDD2() above. I hope this may help.

If you want to populate three select at one go, you can put all the three select box in the getdd2.php and query the database for each base on the data from the first select box.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with this and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: DD1, DD2, DD3 are independent on Magazines dropdown.  Is Onchange function possible in every DD1,DD2,DD3 dropdowns? M requirement is, Selection of magazines dropdown should immediately populate the other 3 dropdowns. If there is any mistake please ignore

Comment: @Jefferson, If you want to populate three select at one go, you can put all the three select box in the getdd2.php and query the database for each base on the data from the first select box (Magazine dropdown)

Comment: Please click the tick icon above if it helps.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the guidance